# CouchDB - fetch every 50 doc in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

For some reasons, I need to fetch every 50 doc in my couchdb.

For example, there are 500 users in my db, and I want to fetch the first, 51th, 101th....451th  user.

How can I get this result through map/reduce function?

(I know that I can set "skip" parameter in url to perform similar behavior, but I'd like to do it through map/reduce)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The key to remember is that CouchDB map/reduce is more like `CREATE INDEX...`, it is not like `SELECT * FROM...`

Map/reduce creates a **static** list of rows. The rows can be in any order you want (it is sorted by the *key* that you emit) but it is impossible for one document to *change the results* of another document.

To illustrate this point, suppose you had a hypothetical view with rows like this. The key is their "position" in the list, and the value is the user name

```
// View rows (conceptual diagram only)
// Key, Value
0     , "mark" // Suppose Alice was created first, 1 week ago
1     , "bob"  // and Bob was created 1 day ago
2     , "evan" // and Evan was created 1 hour ago... so this view is chronological
... // etc.
```

Now you realize that Bob's document had an error. He actually signed up a year ago, not a day ago. You update his timestamp. How should the view look now?

```
// View rows (conceptual diagram only)
// Key, Value
0     , "bob"  // The corrected Bob document was created 1 **year** ago
1     , "mark" // ...and now Mark scoots down to the next position (!!!)
2     , "evan" // ...and Evan stayed the same
... // etc.
```

Here is the problem: in CouchDB, it is *impossible* to affect Mark's row if you only change Bob's document. That is the fundamental architecture. The `(!!!)` label above indicates an impossible feature. The problem is our initial assumption: that we can have a view indicating **absolute** positions of the rows **relative** to each other. (Note, the word *relative* has the same root as *relational*, as in "relational database")

So such a technique is impossible, by reductio ad absurdum.

### Solution

You can do most of what you need with map/reduce. Instead of a hypothetical *position* as the key, use the *timestamp* as the key.

```
// View rows (conceptual diagram only)
// Key, Value
2011-05-06, "bob"  // Bob signed up one year ago
2012-05-05, "mark" // Mark signed up one day ago
2012-05-06, "evan" // Evan one hour ago
... // etc.
```

Of course, the timestamp format is just to make a clear example. You should probably use ISO 8601 format (i.e. what you get from `JSON.stringify(new Date)` in JavaScript).

To get signups newest-first, make a *descending* query to the view; and to get only one row, use the `limit` option.

- To get the newest signup: `?descending=true&limit=1`
- To get the 50th-newest: `?descending=true&limit=1&skip=50`
- To get the 100th-newest: `?descending=true&limit=1&skip=100`

Comment: I want to sort my doc with updated time, and fetch the newest, the 51th newest ..... users.

In ORM of relational db such as MySQL, I can perform this through:
1. sort the data by time
2. User.find(0), User.find(50)

Comment: Awesome! I have updated my answer to approach your problem in the best way CouchDB can.